# Remove special characters from the start and end of a word while counting the words in a file

Tags: python, regex, special-characters, pyspark, word-count

I need to count words in a huge text file but before that, I have to clean the file of special characters in a specific way.

For example -

```
;xyz        -->      xyz      
xyz:        -->     xyz          
xyz!)       -->     xyz!
```

I am using flatMap() to split all the words on space. And then I am trying to remove the special characters which is not working. Please help!

Here is the code I am using ---

The characters to remove are - : ; ! ? ( ) .

```
   >>> input = sc.textFile("file:///home/<...>/Downloads/file.txt")
   >>> input2 = input.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
   >>> def remove(x):
           if x.endsWith(':'):
                x.replace(':','')
                return x
           elif x.endsWith('.'):
               x.replace('.','')
               return x
```

.
.

```
      >>> input3 = input2.map(lambda x: remove(x))
```

Comment: Why is it not working? Please post what you tried.

Comment: In the third example "!" character is not a special char?

Comment: Can you define what are special characters?

Comment: The characters to remove are - : ; ! ? ( ) .
input = sc.textFile("file:///home/<...>/Downloads/file.txt")
>>> input2 = input.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
>>> def remove(x):
       if x.endsWith(':')==true:
   x.replace(':','')
          return x
       elif x.endsWith('.')==true:
          x.replace('.','')
          return x
.
.

>>> input3 = input2.filter(lambda x: remove(x))

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub`

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\S)[^\s\w]+|[^\s\w]+(?!\S)', '', f.read())
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iI1zY3/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that sees if a character is valid, then use `filter()`:

```
def is_valid(char):
    return char.isalpha() or char in "!,." # Whatever extras you want to include

new_string = ''.join(filter(is_valid, old_string)) # No need to ''.join() in Python 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting help of regex:

```
import re

with open('input.txt','r') as fp:
    rx = "[;:\)]+"
    for line in fp:
        data = re.sub(rx, "", line.strip())
        print(data)
```

Code above will read file line by line and emit sanitized content. Depending on content of file it will print:

```
xyz
xyz
xyz!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me-
    def removefromstart(x):
    ...         for i in [':','!','?','.',')','(',';',',']:
    ...                  if x.startswith(i):
    ...                          token = x.replace(i,'')
    ...                          return token
    ...          return x
    ...

> > > ```
> > > def removefromend(x):  
> > > ...          for i in [':','!','?','.',')','(',';',',']:  
> > > ...                  if x.endswith(i):  
> > > ...                          token = x.replace(i,'')  
> > > ...                          return token  
> > > ...         return x
> > > ```